# Handing Secrets in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to Jenkins world, I have a usecase where I have setup a jenkins pipeline using JenkinsFile. As part of deployment stage, we will invoke a few ansible script in the backend to get the image deployed into Kubernetes cluster running in cloud environment. The script expects few secrets in environment variable, so I like to understand which is the **best option to handle secret in Jenkins**, do I need them to **enter into jenkins credentials and read them in jenkins environment tag** like below. Or It is safe to get the value from the user **using input plugin** when executing the pipeline, but if I get from user then I would not able to completely automate pipeline will wait until user input the secret. Could you help in safe way to handle credentials.

```
pipeline{
  agent any {
    environment {
        SECRET_VALUE=credentials('SECRET_VALUE_FROM_JENKINS_CREDENTIALS')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can refer here - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use case, Indeed both approaches as you mentioned above will work.

There shouldn't be any problem in keeping your secrets as Jenkins credentials, in my case, all my secrets are in the Hashicorp vault and my Jenkins credentials point to the vault location as an example...

```
      - usernamePassword:
          scope: GLOBAL
          id: serviceUser
          username: svc_admin
          password: "${secret/xyz/service_user/password}"
          description: My secret service user
```

The Jenkins deployment is via JCasC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, how different to have secret in hashicorp vault and Jenkins credentials. Sorry Just trying to know more about vault .

Comment: Hashicorp vault is more of Industry standard tool when it comes to keep secrets, as think in a way there could be more secrets apart from the one used in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

As jenkins admin I can say it is safe to store credentials in jenkins.

Just create credentials in jenkins and use in a pipeline. Also it's nice to have mask password plugin installed in jenkins, which will mask credentials in jenkins jobs' output.